# Split current date into hourly intervals and get count of production

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I split the current date into hourly intervals like 00:00 - 01:00 for 24 hours and based on that I need to get the count of production which is another column.

This is the code for date column and count column which I wanted to group by hour interval.

```
select count(*),order_start_time_T
from UDA_Order UDA INNER JOIN WORK_Order WO ON WO.order_key = UDA.object_key
where order_state = 'BOOKED' OR order_state = 'CLOSED'
GROUP BY order_start_time_T
```

this returns me

```
Count   order_start_time_T
2   2019-07-02 10:54:27.000
7   2019-07-02 10:55:27.000
1   2019-07-02 11:51:58.000
1   2019-07-02 11:58:41.000
1   2019-07-02 12:19:13.000
```

The result I expect is

```
Count   Hour interval till 24 hours for current day
2   00:00 - 01:00
7   01:00 - 02:00
1   02:00 - 03:00
1   03:00 - 04:00
1   04:00 - 05:00
1   05:00 - 06:00
```

and so on till 24 hours for current day.

Comment: It's not apparent how you are getting "00:00 - 01:00" from "10:54:27.000". Is "00:00 - 01:00" meant to be the time component of `order_start_time_T` or is it an offset from the current datetime returned from `getdate()`, or something else?

Comment: from your query it is not clear that date belong to which table and from which table count will be done.Is there date column in both table which are related in both or can we use only table to find count. then join later.You given info is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `DATEPART` function that returns the part of the date that you need, which is hrs in your case.

```
select count(*), CAST(order_start_time_T AS DATE) StartDate, DATEPART(HOUR, order_start_time_T) StartHr
from UDA_Order UDA INNER JOIN WORK_Order WO ON WO.order_key = UDA.object_key
where order_state = 'BOOKED' OR order_state = 'CLOSED'
GROUP BY CAST(order_start_time_T AS DATE), DATEPART(HOUR, order_start_time_T)
```

But this will not return the results as you wish.
It will returns it like this (for example):

```
Count   StartDate   StartHr 
2   2019-07-02 10
7   2019-07-02 11
1   2019-07-02 12
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try with a helper table, which would hold a start hour (h1 column) and end hour (h2 column). I used a temporary table, but it can be a standard table or a table variable. Column display is just for display purposes.

First of all I populate the table with start and end hour, starting from 0.
Secondly, I use DATEPART to identify an hour of an order (order_start_time_T) and check, in which period that hour depends to.

```
h1   h2    display
---  ---   ---
0    1     00:00 - 01:00
1    2     01:00 - 02:00
....   
23   24    23:00 - 24:00
```

Query:

```
-- Populate time table
   if object_id('tempdb..#t') is not null drop table #t
create table #t (
    h1 tinyint,
    h2 tinyint,
    display varchar(30)
);

declare @i tinyint =0
while @i<24 begin
    insert into #t (h1, h2, display) values(@i, @i+1
        , case when @i<10 then '0' else '' end+cast(@i as varchar)
            +':00 - ' + case when @i<9 then '0' else '' end+ cast(@i+1 as varchar)+':00')
    set @i = @i + 1
end


-- Group per period
select count(*) [Count], t.display
from UDA_Order UDA INNER JOIN WORK_Order WO ON WO.order_key = UDA.object_key
JOIN #t t ON datepart(hour, order_start_time_T) between t.h1 and t.h2
where order_state = 'BOOKED' OR order_state = 'CLOSED'
GROUP BY t.display
```